# Multiple SYSLIB in a property group or multiple property groups in a COBOL program in Rational Developer for System Z

Tags: cobol, copybook, rational-developer-for-i

I'm wondering if I can set more than one SYSLIB in a property group or more than one property groups in a COBOL program. I'm using Rational Developer for System Z v9. My program requires copybooks that are from different sources and as far as I tried and googled, I can't seem to find any references to it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mind me, I noticed that we can put more than one path in SYSLIB by using a space in between. Just didn't read detailed enough.

Comment: No problem. If you update this answer with an example of doing this, then when the system allows, mark it as Accept (click on the ghostly tick, I think). It may help people in the future with the same question.